# Strange Django ''BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()" query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm optimising my code which was making far too many queries on start.

I'm getting to almost the bare minimum now, and have started coming across the following:

```
QUERY = 'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()
```

This seems to be used almost every single time and practically doubles the number of queries made - but I don't think it is actually doing anything (apart from opening up a connection to the DB and wasting time and CPU).

Can anyone tell me what it is, why it is necessary, and if it isn't, how I can remove it?

I'm viewing my queries using `django.db.connection.queries`.

Django - 1.8
Python - 3.4
with sqlite as the DB.

EDIT:

Providing examples for context is a little bit odd, as it's almost every single action I take which requires queries causes this query to popup (alongside the query I want).

But here are a couple examples:

Creating an object which has a default timestamp of now:

```
session = Session()
session.save()
```

Provides the following queries:

```
QUERY = 'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()
QUERY = 'INSERT INTO "tracker_session" ("name", "session_date", "number_of_courts", "finished", "session_tracker") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' - PARAMS = ('', '2015-06-17', 4, False, '')
```

Similarly updating a group of objects to change a particular attribute:

(the `self` here is just an object with a `ManyToMany` attribute - `players`)

```
self.players.all().update(available=True)
```

yields:

```
QUERY = 'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()
QUERY = 'UPDATE "tracker_person" SET "available" = %s WHERE "tracker_person"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" AS Col1 FROM "tracker_person" U0 INNER JOIN "tracker_session_players" U1 ON ( U0."id" = U1."person_id" ) WHERE U1."session_id" = %s)' - PARAMS = (True, 19)
```

the second query is always what I want, I have no idea what the first `QUERY = 'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()` is for.

Comment: Without any context it's next to impossible to say something about that statement.

Comment: @KlausD. Added some examples to help with context, let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the BEGIN queries are a work around in the sqlite backend to deal with quirks of sqlite. I think you'll will see one BEGIN for every write that you do outside of a transaction.

If you want to dig into the code further, start [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9aac99e96d100b34b6daa3a137531eff4f17076e/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L297).

So there isn't anything you can do about the queries, but I wouldn't worry, I doubt they will have any noticeable effect on performance. If you are really worried about db performance of writes then you can try a different database backend.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the code it seems you are right. I'll probably migrate to a new backend soon.